# Conditionally select DTO to validation in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I have a POST API that's expecting a payload that includes a `type` field. I also use groups in one DTO to conditionally declare which validation to run based on this `type` field.

But now, I want to separate each validations into their own DTO by using the `transform` method of my custom validation pipe as seen below:

```
export class EmployeeValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private readonly options?: ValidationPipeOptions) {}

    transform(value: EmployeesCreationInterface, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<any> {
        const { metatype } = metadata;

        let instance = undefined;
        switch (value.type) {
            case EmployeeTypes.Director:
                instance = new DirectorSkuCreationDto(value)
                break;
            case EmployeeTypes.Secretary:
                instance = new SecretaryCreationDto(value)
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if(instance){
            const newMetaData: ArgumentMetadata = {
                ...metadata,
                metatype: instance // Throws because metatype is not the correct type 
            }
        }

        const validationPipe = new ValidationPipe(this.options);

        return validationPipe.transform(value, newMetaData);
    }
}
```

My goal here is to manually specify the DTO that's being used in the validator and I tried doing it by passing the correct instance as the metatype but this has not worked.

Any idea how I can go about this or if there's a different approach to take altogether?

Answer (score 0):

you're encountering an issue where the metatype property of the metadata object is not the correct type after assigning it to the instance of the DTO.

To fix this, you can manually set the metatype property of the newMetaData object to the correct type based on the value of the type field. For example:

```
if (instance) {
  let dtoMetatype;
  switch (value.type) {
    case EmployeeTypes.Director:
      dtoMetatype = DirectorSkuCreationDto;
      break;
    case EmployeeTypes.Secretary:
      dtoMetatype = SecretaryCreationDto;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  const newMetaData: ArgumentMetadata = {
    ...metadata,
    metatype: dtoMetatype,
  };

  const validationPipe = new ValidationPipe(this.options);

  return validationPipe.transform(instance, newMetaData);
}
```

In this example, we're creating a new variable dtoMetatype to hold the correct type based on the value.type field. Then, we set the metatype property of the newMetaData object to dtoMetatype. Finally, we pass in instance instead of value to the validationPipe.transform method.

This should allow you to use separate DTOs for each type of input and conditionally validate them based on the type field.

Comment: this still results in the same error.